# Meta query broken since 4.7.4 Update

Tags: custom-post-types, meta-query, pre-get-posts, automatic-updates

To sort a custom post type `event` by a custom field `event_date`, I created the following action. This worked flawlessly until today, when our site automatically updated to WordPress 4.7.4. Now the query doesn't return any posts on the `event` archive. Additionally, there are no events listed in the admin panel, but the table header shows the number of published and planned posts (see image, note: *Veranstaltungen*=events).
[image: German text, but it'll speak for itself I hope]

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', '348541_sort_events_by_date');

function 348541_sort_events_by_date( \WP_Query $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_post_type_archive( 'event' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_query', [
            [
                'key'     => 'event_date',
                'value'   => date( 'd-m-Y' ),
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type'    => 'date'
            ]
        ] );

        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_date');
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC');
    }
} );
```

I looked up the release notes but couldn't find anything, even in the changed files list there didn't seem to be anything query related, but maybe I've just missed something.
Why does this query fail to fetch my posts?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem, though I cannot explain why or how things went the way they did - the date to compare events by had the wrong date format: `date( 'd-m-Y' )` should have been `date( 'Y-m-d' )`.
The comparison worked until the update, so something must've changed about the way WordPress stores date input.

Comment: since this is your code adding the events, it is unlikely any core change caused it. In any case the original way seems like it is the wrong way to compare dates, and what you are doing now is the right way, so if I am right, this is just luck that made it work before

Comment: @MarkKaplun Seems like it, though I wonder how the date comparison ever worked if the format was plain wrong - that should not have been working before...

Comment: It's unlikely to have been 4.7.4's fault, but you can confirm this by downgrading to 4.7.3 and checking the result. I would also note that the current time and date has an impact on this, the results on the 2017/4/21 might not match those of 2017/4/20, or rather the 2017th day of April in the year 20 AD, may not be interpreted by MySQL the same as the 2017th day of April in the year 21 AD

Comment: @TomJNowell As an end user, I don't care that much about guilt, as long as things work on my client's site... Nevertheless I expect PHPs `date()` to return the same date format no matter if its 2017 or 2020. The same goes for HTML5 date input fields in the admin panel, if I select a date, I expect the same format to be stored in the database.

Comment: The format in the database would be a unix timestamp, the only date handling changes were in the REST API which is unrelated to your issue. Figuring these out will prevent future reoccurrences as well as highlight other potential problems in a codebase

Comment: Under the hood, MySQL doesn't see dates as their individual year / month / day units, they're compared as simple monolithic 8 digit numbers. This only works when date strings are organized in order from coarse to fine units. It's often the case that the wrong format coincidentally gives you the correct results, which makes the issue hard to immediately spot.